# SAML2 AngularJs Spring security

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-mybatis

I have implemented SAML authentication using Spring MVC. I am also using Angular JS along with Spring. In current Project, Anuglarjs is loaded from Spring but AngularJS is single page application, SAML is working fine in this scenario. Now Project requirement has changed and we are deploying Angularjs code on one server and Spring mvc code on another server. As we authenticate SAML using spring mvc so when i run both projects on same browser and login using SAML in spring mvc and try to connect from angularjs to spring. authentication fails.

How can I handle this scenario? Is there any way to implement SAML2 with Spring code and Angular Code on different servers?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a good solution is to perform the SAML authentication and then turn the authenticated user into some JWT identity which is passed to the AngularJS app and re-used for the next calls.

You can do that with the [spring-webmvc-pac4j security library](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j) which supports both SAML and JWT authentication mechanisms.